# Is it possible to put select input with values from database in Dynamically Add/Remove input fields?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm creating a Dynamically Add/Remove input fields for my project. One of the column has a select type of input and the options needs to be from a table in database. It is working perfectly on the first row but when I needed to add more fields, it doesn't work. Is it possible to put php codes on .append function in jquery?

I tried doing the same process on the first row for .append function, but when I add more fields, it doesn't add anything. When I removed the php codes, it is working, but not with the options from database. I don't know if I have syntax error in displaying the values from database in append function.

```
<?php
   <tr>                       
    <td>
      <select class="form-control" name="procedures[]">
        <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM services";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
              {  
               echo '<option>'.$row['s_name'].'</option>
                    ';
              }
  ?>
      </select> 
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control name_list" /></td>  
   <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>  
  </tr>
```

This is the append function that add more text fields just like the format of row above.

```
  <script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){  
  var i=1;  
  $('#add').click(function(){  
       i++;  
       $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select class="form-control" name="procedures[]"><?php $sql="SELECT * FROM services"; $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<option>'".$row['s_name']."'</option>";}?></select> </td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="amount[]" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">x</button></td></tr>');  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });  
  $('#submit').click(function(){            
       $.ajax({  
            url:"name.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                 alert(data);  
                 $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
            }  
       });  
  });  
 });  
 </script>
```

I expect that I can add more input fields as same with the first row which has a  column of select input with options from a table in database. [Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9J7u.png)

Comment: It's working! echo '<option>'.$row['s_name'].'</option>'; I just change the syntax into this.

Comment: Well done. Glad to hear it.